# Assemble Error for AVX2

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, avx2

I've tried to compile a AVX2 program with gcc(g++). But it didn't work right.

```
#include<immintrin.h>
....
__m256i _vector256  = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)pin);
__m256i _vectorMask = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)mask_hbits); 
_vector256 = _mm256_slli_epi32 (_vector256, AVX_LOGDESC); // AVX_LOGDESC == 4
__m256i _vectorRes = _mm256_and_si256(_vector256, _vectorMask);
....
```

My compile command is (as one line in Makefile):

```
g++ avx_shift.cpp -c -mavx2
```

I also tried this one:

```
g++ avx_shift.cpp -c -march=native
```

But the error messages were same:

```
/tmp/ccSFs6U0.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccSFs6U0.s:1083: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpslld'
/tmp/ccSFs6U0.s:1091: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vpand'
....
```

The assembly code (added the line number):

```
vmovdqa 988(%rsp), %ymm0    # __A, D.48219
movl    984(%rsp), %eax # __B, tmp205
movl    %eax, -120(%rsp)    # tmp205, %sfp
vmovd   -120(%rsp), %xmm6   # %sfp, tmp205
vpslld  %xmm6, %ymm0, %ymm0 # tmp205, D.48219, D.48220      // 1083
....
vmovdqa 668(%rsp), %ymm0    # __B, tmp220
vmovdqa 700(%rsp), %ymm1    # __A, tmp221
vpand   %ymm0, %ymm1, %ymm0 # tmp220, tmp221, D.48215       // 1091
....
```

My gcc(g++) version is 4.8.0. My OS version is Centos6.5 X86_64. I've confirmed that my CPU supports AVX2 instructions. So who can help me find the errors?

Comment: What's your assembler (binutils) version? 2.22 assembles that fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two source lines you pasted shouldn't, and on my machine don't, generate any `vpslld` or `vpand` instructions. Use the `-S -g -fverbose-asm` switches to ask for assembly source and try to find the matching source lines.

Comment: Sorry.I don't how to format codes in comments, so I post the code in the quertion.

Comment: Seems to compile fine on my debian gcc 4.7.2 and on http://gcc.godbolt.org using ubuntu g++ 4.8

Comment: I built the gcc4.8 from the source, since the oringinal version in Centos is 4.4.7. If the error is about the compiler, is there any special option for the make command of gcc?

Comment: It sounds more like the assembler not the compiler, since you have pasted the asm output and that looks okay.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I've already solved this problem. It seems that the version of binutils(2.20) is too low.
I've built the binutils 2.22 and the issue resolved.